# Could not find the controller end point when passing a string as a parameter in Web API 2 put as async

Tags: c#, wpf, web, asp.net-web-api2, controllers

Code for controller

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPut]
[Route("TopHandler/{studentId}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateClass(string studentId, String projectId)
{
    var response = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //  Some Code here
    });

    return response;
}
```

Code for Controller call

```
 await VML.Client.PutAsJsonAsync("TopHandler/" + studentId, projectId);
```

Unfortunately this end point cannot be found by the request and it gives 404 
I am passing a string as a parameter . What would possibly go wrong here ?

Comment: Have you considered adding the projectId to the Route?

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Scratch that, my bad, I didn't notice the PutAsJsonAsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is when you call PutAsJsonAsync the parameters are converted to JSON and sent in the BODY of the request.

At a guess you should change your signature to:

```
[Route("TopHandler/{studentId}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateClass([FromBody]string JSON)
```